# Как обратиться к элементу Windows Forms из статичного асинхронного метода класса Program?

Tags: c#, winforms

Например хочу

```
class Program
{
    public static async void Pot(int x)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //разные вычисления
            Form1.lable1.text = "123456";
        });            
    }
}
```

Если насильно делать Элемент Windows Forms статичным - получаю ошибку
"пытаетесь запустить не из того потока, в котором он был создан"

Если статичным не делать. Требует ссылку на объект, которую никак не дать естественно.

Как решается эта проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public static async void OutputText()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //типа делаются какие-то вычисления
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            //
            var form1 = Application.OpenForms
                               .OfType<Form>()
                               .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Form1");

            if (form1 == null) return;

            var label = form1.Controls
                             .OfType<Label>()
                             .FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "_labelOutput");

            if (label != null && label.InvokeRequired)
            {
                label.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    label.Text = "123456";
                }));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Если в асинхронном методе это запустить. Опять получаем ошибку: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'lb' не из того потока, в котором он был создан"

Comment: Изменил, добавил той асинхронности, которую вы хотите.

Comment: Благодарю. В многопотоке не должно ошибок возникать? Или лучше в lock (object) спрятать момент обращения к форме ?

Comment: Извините, но я всей картины вашего кода не вижу, а потому могу ответить только, если считаете нужным - попробуйте, но принцип: "Работает? Тогда не тронь.", никто не отменял.